# Where can I ask questions about demographics, human mortality?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

If there's a part of SE which is fitting for this question, please move it there. Or break it down to me gently.

I've got a question about **mortality rates**. I want to find the mortality or death rates for white American women for every year from 1920 until 1996.
The purpose is to compare this general population mortality with that of specific sub groups.
I want to research a claim that a specific group of US white women have a mortality rate of 3.2%, which is four times higher than the "General Population"  which is supposed to be 0.8%. Four times as high seems to me a bit much.

**What did I do already?**

a. I've looked at the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data-visualization/mortality-trends/#data-tables), but they only seem to report about **Life Expectancy**, not mortality by **Year**, Gender and **Race**. I'm specifically not looking at any life expectancy answers.

b. [This](https://www.msn.com/en-us/health/wellness/life-expectancy-the-year-you-were-born/ss-BB1ew4aZ) seemed to be the answer to my question, but, in the end, it wasn't, because I couldn't find where it said: *"Were you born in 1920, the percentage of your cohort that has died before the age of 20, of 30 of 50 is .... percent."*
But of course, I might've missed something.

c. Maybe [this site](https://www.worldlifeexpectancy.com/usa/life-expectancy-white-female) came the closest, but I couldn't make head nor tail of it, since it's focused on Cause of Death, not **Mortality by Birth Year**.

Now, I've looked at the sites of the network, but aside from [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), nothing seems to be the right fit for this type of question.

EDIT
I've found something on the CDC site here https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/dvs/hist290_0039.pdf   Please see page 7, ''White Females''.

This seems to answer my question but I've got a question about it:
The mortality of the under 1 year olds seems very high, higher than the mortality for **ALL Ages**. How can this be?

Comment: Perhaps [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: There's ['data-request' tag on OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) for raw data, but for explanations about your query, maybe [history.se] or [stats.se] (Statistics.SE) could explain, depending on the topic and their POV.